# Can't play a sound from Python 3

Tags: python, audio

**Hello, I am trying to play a sound in Python, I tried using playsound and other libraries(AudioPlayer,pydub).
I use this script for playsound :

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound('/audio.wav')
```

I only get this on my computer, do I need something else to be able to play a wav file?

I get this error :**
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 35, in _playsoundWin
winCommand('open "' + sound + '" alias', alias)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\playsound.py", line 30, in winCommand
'\n    ' + errorBuffer.value.decode())
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 35: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mre] so that we can see the code that produces this error.

Comment: Try removing the slash from the filename?

Comment: I tried removing the slash and with other files, it might be because of ffmpeg not on my computer, I will try with ffmpeg installed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you share your whole code for more clarification. By the way,

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 35:
invalid continuation byte
```

you get this error when same or greater amount of bytes or Unicode strings can’t be represented in any kind of encoding.